# Lost saved game on the MyBoy GBA emulator?

Tags: technical-issues, my-boy

For a couple of days I was playing Pokemon Ruby on the "*MyBoy!*" Gameboy Advance  emulator on Android and I progressed very far on that game. But today day as I load the game, it displays an option of new game, my saved game is lost all of a sudden.

Why did this happen and how could I retrieve the saved game back again? I used the in-game feature to save my progress all this long.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't altered the contents of your devices internal storage since your save was last present, the save file can be located from these paths:

```
sdcard/MyBoy/save/%ROMNAME%.sav

mnt/sdcard/MyBoy/save/%ROMNAME%.sav

storage/emulated/0/MyBoy/save/%ROMNAME%.sav
```

*Note: "`sdcard`" and "`0`" both represent the storage root. [Legacy](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi4gNCqlZbVAhUJqlQKHdPiDX0QFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNHTlfqYI4JmwOddVzmmnC40pKbX-A) devices typically use the `mnt` path.*

If you can't find the save file there, or *anywhere* else on your device, it has most likely been deleted.